# Google Calendar Sync Script for iCal URL feed produces multiple instances of same calendar entry

Tags: calendar, synchronization, google-workspace

I want to have Google Calendar (from my paid G-Suite) sync with my Cliniko clinic calendar (which has an iCal feed url) as often as possible (five minutes would be acceptable).

By default, the sync time seems to be around 12 to 24 hours, which is non-functional for me.

I have attempted to use [this script](https://script.google.com/a/willnapier.com/d/1QeZFLSM1EkuFvYcryECI_xH-IZVe1-IxGRq_n6OoXp1CmVtSeTeigEx4/edit?usp=drive_web) by Derek Antrican on G-Suite. I added my information.

Initially it didn't work but when I changed the entry in the script from name `[My first and last name]` to `[my email address with G Suite hosted domain]`, it started syncing.

However, it gave me error messages (I include only the top/last couple of items out of many):

> apps-scripts-notifications@google.com
> 06:19 (8 hours ago)
> to me
>
> Your script, Copy of ICS/ICAL sync, has recently failed to finish
> successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure
> the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving
> future failure notifications, click here.
>
> Summary: Error Message Count Service invoked too many times for one day: email.
>
> (line 143, file "Code")  108  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
>
> (line 143, file "Code")  1  Start Function Error Message Trigger End 4/7/18 5:41 PM  main  We're sorry, a server error
> occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
>
> (line 143, file "Code")
> time-based  4/7/18 5:41 PM  4/7/18 5:42 PM  main  Service invoked too
> many times for one day: email.
>
> (line 143, file "Code")  time-based
> 4/7/18 5:43 PM

I believe the timestamps are not UK time - these happened overnight in UK or in early morning.

I then changed the script and ran/installed it again, with the one change being that the time interval went from 1 min to 5 mins.

I have not received any error messages yet (but they may be building up somewhere and not emailed to me yet).

However what I am noticing is that events are being added multiple instances:

So an important goal is to stop this duplication from happening (with many thanks for any help):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you first experiment by looking at the logs.  The script has the option:

`var addEventsToCalendar = true;`

Set this to false, and look at the logs.  You can also have the script send you email reminders, so you get more timely information on what is going on.  See:

```
var emailWhenAdded = false; //Will email you when an event is added to your calendar
var email = ""; //OPTIONAL: If "emailWhenAdded" is set to true, you will need to provide your email
```

Comment: Thank you BBCMicro. I notice that the logs show that some entries are repeated several times, and others are not. In addition I got an email from google apps scripts saying that it was executing too many times in one day. However I have no idea how to proceed currently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem turned out to be the external service generating new event UIDs every time the .ics file was retrieved (which more or less defeats the purpose of iCal UIDs).

An (admittedly rather inelegant) workaround is to concatenate the start and end times, location and description (thus creating a more or less unique identifier) and use this value in the FID tag instead of the iCal UID. This should work unless you need support for recurring events, but that functionality is likely broken anyway if your service keeps generating new UIDs.

In other words, replace this:

```
if (item.includes("UID")){
        currentEvent.id = item.split("UID:")[1];
        feedEventIds.push(currentEvent.id);
      }
```

With this:

```
currentEvent.id = (currentEvent.startTime+currentEvent.endTime+currentEvent.location+currentEvent.title);
feedEventIds.push(currentEvent.id);
```

In addition, remove the part of the script relating to modifying existing events, as this will now happen every time the ID changes.